# How do I add for() loop index identifier to label name?

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, wpf-controls

I am attempting to dynamically add content to labels in `WPF` from an object in a list.
I can add the content from the Object fine by hard-coding the index number:

```
// assign forecast values to 5 user interface labels

Forecast fc1 = day.Weather.getForecastInList(0);
day1Label.Content = fc1.Day;
day1ConditionLabel.Content = fc1.ForecastCondition;
day1TempLabel.Content = formatHiLow(fc1.TemperatureHigh, fc1.TemperatureLow);

Forecast fc2 = day.Weather.getForecastInList(1);
day2Label.Content = fc2.Day;
day2ConditionLabel.Content = fc2.ForecastCondition;
day2TempLabel.Content = formatHiLow(fc2.TemperatureHigh, fc2.TemperatureLow);

etc...
```

But then I would have to repeat a lot of the assignment code for each of the 5 labels.

I have attempted to use a `for()` loop which works fine to get each of the objects from the list but won't let me rename the labels e.g.

```
// assign forecast values to 5 user interface labels
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    Forecast fc+(i+1) = day.Weather.getForecastInList(i);
    day+(i+1)+Label.Content = fc+(i+1)+.Day;
}
```

How can I dynamically identify `WPF` labels using the index in a `for()` loop?

Comment: delete all that and use an `ItemsControl`. Start reading [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/).

Comment: Use an `ObservableCollection<ForeCast>` a `ListView` or `ItemsControl` and so on

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend this but to answer your question, theres a possibility:

Create a list which contains all your labels:

```
List<Label> dayLabels = new List<Label>();
dayLabels.Add(day1Label);
dayLabels.Add(day2Label);
//and so on...
```

Loop through all the labels:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    Forecast fc = day.Weather.getForecastInList(i);
    dayLabels.ElementAt(i).Content = fc.Day;
}
```